# How do I query current and previous months data from a DB that uses UNIX EPOCH time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, epoch

I am trying to query a DB that is in UNIX EPOCH time format, so I can't use any of the standard modifiers that I am used to. I heard Carbon was useful for these things however I still haven't mastered it's use.

```
    $date = Carbon::today();
    $this_months_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::where('time',$date->copy()->format('m'))->sum('data');
    $one_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');


    $two_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $three_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $four_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $five_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $six_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $seven_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $eight_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $nine_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $ten_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
    $eleven_month_agos_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::sum('data');
```

So how would I go about doing that?
This is what the collection looks like when you are not filtering anything. As you can tell the 'time' is in EPOCH UNIX time.

```
Collection {#9512 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Feed115 {#9511 ▼
      #connection: "emoncms"
      #table: "feed_115"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:2 [▼
        "time" => 1552716000
        "data" => 222.314
      ]
      #original: array:2 [▼
        "time" => 1552716000
        "data" => 222.314
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Feed115 {#9510 ▼
      #connection: "emoncms"
      #table: "feed_115"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:2 [▼
        "time" => 1552629600
        "data" => 405.903
      ]
      #original: array:2 [▼
        "time" => 1552629600
        "data" => 405.903
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried this but it did not work:

```
    $date = Carbon::today();

    /* Yearly Realtime Consumption data feed */
    $startthis = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->timestamp;
    $endthis = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->timestamp;
    $this_months_values = (new $propdash->custommenuitems->monthly_real_time_feed)::where('time',[$startthis, $endthis])->sum('data');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this for an individual month:

```php
$start = Carbon::parse('-5 months')->startOfMonth()->timestamp;
$end = Carbon::parse('-5 months')->endOfMonth()->timestamp;

$five_month_agos_values = YourModel::whereBetween('time', [$start, $end])->sum('data');
```

Or if you don't like the idea of parsing strings:

```php
$start = Carbon::now()->subMonths(5)->startOfMonth()->timestamp;
```

Comment: I couldn't tell you tell you if there was any advantage or disadvantage to parsing strings or not. But thank you for taking the  time to help.. I'm going to go try these out now.. stand by and thank you!!!

Comment: @FrankBarcenas It's really just a style choice

Comment: I tried just to get the current month but it did not work.. I updated what to show show what i tried.

Comment: @FrankBarcenas can you define "didn't work"? Was there an error?

Comment: oops I overlooked the wherebetween